# How can I ignore fixtures when I run Pytest --collect-only?

Tags: python, pytest

I am collecting test names and writing them to a text file with:

`pytest --collect-only -quiet >list_of_tests.txt`

One of my tests has a fixture that runs the test 67 times.  When I collect my tests, I end up with 67 versions of this test appended with [reply_type0], [reply_type1], [reply_type2], ...

Is there a way to collect tests while ignoring fixtures so I only get one test collected without the fixture appended to the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not really possible in `pytest`, you should filter the collected test items by adding a custom `pytest` plugin with a hook that modifies the items during the collection process.

Just create a `conftest.py` file in your project directory with this inside:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    filtered_items = []

    for item in items:
        test_name = item.nodeid.split('[')[0]
        if test_name not in [filtered_item.nodeid for filtered_item in filtered_items]:
            filtered_items.append(item)

    items[:] = filtered_items
```